# Extract metadata from a MP3/OGG with Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, ogg

In my final project for this course, I need to use Java to make an aplication with real use. I chose to make a music library, but I need to extract metadata from all MP3/OGG files in the library folder.

For MP3 files I think with jid3 (https://blinkenlights.org/jid3/) it's ok, but... What can I make with OGG files? Is there any Java library for both files types?

Thanks! And sorry for my english.

Comment: [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) reads MP3, Ogg and FLAC. Note that asking for library recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Uh sorry. I'm asking about extract metadata from Ogg/FLAC files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you that, Juanjo. http://diariodeuninformaticorenegado.hol.es/es/portfolio/ragml-rename-automatic-and-generate-music-library/ !! :D

This program generate a html library of a directory.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to make it using only Java (I'm not sure if C++ can be valid here...)